# Limits of square root of sum

Tags: limits, roots, average

Does the square root have an "averaging" property? That is, for a square root of a sum, will outliers be more "irrelevant", the more summands we add?  My intuition tells me yes, but I can't figure out how to prove it. In other words, does the following hold?

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{nx+y}\approx\sqrt{nx}$

Comment: $\approx$ would be more accurate.

Comment: The right hand side of the equation contains an $n$.  The left hand side of the equation is the result of a limit as $n$ approaches infinity and so the left-hand side of the equation after evaluated does *not* contain an $n$.  What you mean to ask is probably instead whether or not $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{nx+y}}{\sqrt{nx}}=1$.  The answer is yes (*assuming nonzero $x$*).

Comment: As for how to prove it, multiply numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and distribute to get the above limit is equal to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x+\frac{y}{n}}}{\sqrt{x}}$.  From here, it should be immediately apparent the result, or if you prefer an $\epsilon$-$N$ argument, how to proceed.